# Xcode 5 storyboard compile failure

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, jenkins

I'm running Xcode 5 and building for iOS 7. When I try to build this project for archiving I get this error. I get it on my local machine and on my jenkins build server. I have gone through the storyboard and I am not finding any reason for this error. It builds just fine on simulator and device. I am not even sure what runtime.nib is though addEditHCPViewController.nib is reference to one of the View Controllers inside of the storyboard. Any ideas?

```
CompileStoryboard myApp/Profiles.storyboard
    cd "/builds/Company/workspace/myApp"
    setenv IBSC_MINIMUM_COMPATIBILITY_VERSION 6.1
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    setenv XCODE_DEVELOPER_USR_PATH /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/..
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool --errors --warnings --notices --minimum-deployment-target 6.1 --output-format human-readable-text --compile /builds/Company/workspace/myApp/build/Distribution-iphoneos/myApp.app/Profiles.storyboardc /builds/Company/workspace/myApp/myApp/Profiles.storyboard
/* com.apple.ibtool.document.warnings */
/builds/Company/workspace/myApp/myApp/Profiles.storyboard:jlW-RT-oUY: warning: 2 views are vertically ambiguous.
/builds/Company/workspace/myApp/myApp/Profiles.storyboard:1Qm-h4-IZr: warning: Position is ambiguous for "Picker".
/builds/Company/workspace/myApp/myApp/Profiles.storyboard:d8p-iA-2QW: warning: Frame for "Button" will be different at run time.
/* com.apple.ibtool.errors */
/builds/Company/workspace/myApp/myApp/Profiles.storyboard: error: Compilation failed. Unable to write to path: /builds/Company/workspace/myApp/build/Distribution-iphoneos/myApp.app/Profiles.storyboardc
    Underlying Errors:
        Description: The file ‚Äúruntime.nib‚Äù doesn‚Äôt exist.
        Failure Reason: The file doesn‚Äôt exist.
        Underlying Errors:
            Description: The operation couldn‚Äôt be completed. No such file or directory
            Failure Reason: No such file or directory
        Description: ‚ÄúProfiles.storyboardc‚Äù couldn‚Äôt be removed.
        Failure Reason: The file doesn‚Äôt exist.
        Underlying Errors:
            Description: The operation couldn‚Äôt be completed. No such file or directory
            Failure Reason: No such file or directory

CompileStoryboard myApp/Profiles.storyboard
    cd "/builds/Company/workspace/myApp"
    setenv IBSC_MINIMUM_COMPATIBILITY_VERSION 6.1
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    setenv XCODE_DEVELOPER_USR_PATH /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/..
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool --errors --warnings --notices --minimum-deployment-target 6.1 --output-format human-readable-text --compile /builds/Company/workspace/myApp/build/Distribution-iphoneos/myApp.app/Profiles.storyboardc /builds/Company/workspace/myApp/myApp/Profiles.storyboard
/* com.apple.ibtool.document.warnings */
/builds/Company/workspace/myApp/myApp/Profiles.storyboard:d8p-iA-2QW: warning: Frame for "Button" will be different at run time.
/builds/Company/workspace/myApp/myApp/Profiles.storyboard:jlW-RT-oUY: warning: 2 views are vertically ambiguous.
/builds/Company/workspace/myApp/myApp/Profiles.storyboard:1Qm-h4-IZr: warning: Position is ambiguous for "Picker".
/* com.apple.ibtool.errors */
/builds/Company/workspace/myApp/myApp/Profiles.storyboard: error: Compilation failed. Unable to write to path: /builds/Company/workspace/myApp/build/Distribution-iphoneos/myApp.app/Profiles.storyboardc
    Underlying Errors:
        Description: The file ‚ÄúaddEditHCPViewController.nib‚Äù doesn‚Äôt exist.
        Failure Reason: The file doesn‚Äôt exist.
        Underlying Errors:
            Description: The operation couldn‚Äôt be completed. No such file or directory
            Failure Reason: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Are you using AutoLayout?

Comment: Yes, I am using auto layout.

Comment: Are using it in Storyboard for adjusting your content or you are not using it at all? You may try to disable it in your Storyboard file and then try to archive again.

Comment: I am using it to adjust the content. I will try disabling it and see if it archives even if it doesn't look good, just to isolate the problem.

Comment: Disabling auto layouts did not work.

Comment: have a look in the project navigator. Can you spot any files that are highlighted red?

Comment: None, they are all there and it builds fine for simulator/device.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I found the answer to this. During a merge in git, the project file had not been merged properly and Profiles.storyboard was being included as a resource twice. When it tried to compile the same resource the second time, it would fail.

Comment: Open up your Build Phases and look under Copy Bundle Resources. Look at all of the files and see if the storyboard shows up twice in this list. Alternatively and to fix the issue if it does show up in the Copy Bundle Resources phase: Open up the project.pbxproj file and search for the name of the storyboard. Check to see if something seems out of place or the record is duplicated with different hashes.

Comment: thank you so much! in my project there was the launch storyboard added twice to the copy bundle resources which caused the problem!

Comment: In my case I don't see the storyboard added twice in the copy bundle resource.

Comment: Interesting note, my project is suffering this same issue due to a botched merge as well.  The infamous Xcode project file strikes again!

Answer (score 5):

I just Cleaned the project, then built it again, afterwards the error disappeared.

Answer (score 2):

Just feel I should add that I had this problem for a while and had no clue how to solve it.

Turns out one of my Storyboard IDs had a slash in (/) which was causing the error. Removing this slash resolved the error!

Hope this helps some people!

Answer (score 1):

Removing "/" in the storyboard Id is fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

@imran-ahmed solved the problem. I worked on this problem for a couple hours and finally found the comment about the '/' in a StoryBoard ID.  A year later and the '/' in the StoryBoard ID still kills Xcode compile. That was my problem and simply deleting the '/' solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue, in my case I had not checked the Target Membership option. Make sure it is checked otherwise Xcode won't be able to find it.

[image: ScreenShot]